# PHP - function name($variable = FALSE) - purpose of FALSE declaration - example from Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, function

This is probably quite a simply question but it's something I have never come across until recently.

I was beginning to research PHP frameworks and delved into the tutorial on Codeigniter.

When building the dynamic news section pages, the following method is defined:

```
public function get_news($slug = FALSE) {
```

in `news_model.php`. The method then goes on to check if `($slug === FALSE)` to return all the database rows or, if not, get the new item corresponding to the passed `$slug`.

Can someone tell me what `($slug = FALSE)` does when defining the method? Excluding it returns a missing argument warning.

The full method is:

```
public function get_news($slug) {
    if ($slug === FALSE) {
        $query = $this->db->get('news');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

I realise that this isn't going to be specific to Codeigniter but I thought I'd use the example in the CI tutorial to explain my confusion.

Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public function get_news($slug = FALSE) {
```

What this says is that if the function is called without passing a variable then use `false` as the value for `$slug`

Comment: Thanks, nice simple answer. I checked up on the php manual afterwards but didn't make the connect even then.

Answer (score 2):

PHP calls these [default arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php), and they are a way of providing a value for a variable that is not passed to the function when it is called. So given your function (I made it a function instead of a method for the purposes of the demonstration):

```
function get_news($slug = FALSE) {
    var_dump($slug);
}

echo "With no arguments: ";
get_news();

echo "With a slug (abc): ";
get_news('abc');
```

([Codepad Demo](http://codepad.org/JUNtmAyn))

When no value for `$slug` is passed into `get_news()`, it assumes the default value in the function's signature, `false`. However, if a value is provided for `$slug` when `get_news()` is called, then within the function, `$slug` will be this value (`'abc'` in the example).

This can be particularly useful when specifying arguments that aren't often needed. Take care in carefully reading the documentation though because only certain values can be specified as a default. Those are: scalars (booleans, strings, integers, and floats), `array`s, and NULL. You cannot define a parameters default to be a non-scalar such as an object, object method, or object property, function call, or constant (basically anything non-scalar or that is an expression).

Ones that work:

```
function test($a = false) {}

function test($a = 'default') {}

function test($a = 1) {}

function test($a = array()) {}

function test($a = SOME_CONST) {}

function test($a = SomeClass::someConstant) {}
```

([Codepad Demo](http://codepad.org/33q9e304))

Ones that **will not** work:

```
function test($a = someFunc()) {}

function test($a = new stdClass()) {}

function test($a = SomeClass::staticMethod()) {}

function test($a = 1 + 1) {} // this includes all expressions (and string concatenation)
```

For the ones that don't, a common paradigm is to make the parameter default to `NULL` and then assign the variable a default value within the function if its value is `NULL`. Example:

```
function getDefault() {
    return 'some dynamic default';
}

function test($a = NULL) {
    if($a === NULL) {
        $a = getDefault();
    }

    var_dump($a);
}

test();    // string(20) "some dynamic default"
test('a'); // string(1) "a"
```

([Codepad Demo](http://codepad.org/dJ9AYpCR))

Comment: A great detailed answer, I almost feel embarrassed the OP chose my answer over this one. +1

Answer (score 1):

It gives it a default value so you don't have to give one when you call the function. It allows you to do `get_news()` instead of always doing `get_news(FALSE)` and only give the argument when you want something other than the default, ie: `get_news(TRUE)`

ETA: In this case the argument would likely be FALSE means no slug, and a string is a slug. So it would be `get_news('category')`.

Answer (score 0):

"Can someone tell me what ($slug = FALSE) does when defining the method?"

The `$slug = false` means that it is an optional argument, which will default to `false` if not provided.

Removing the `= false` will then cause that argument to be required. Hence your error.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function FUnction_Name ($Var = false){ }
```

This is defining a default it not specified in the function call... Example:

```
class Test { 
  public function Return_Test ($Variable = false){
    if ($Variable === false){
      return false; 
    }
    return true;


  }

}
```

Then Calling:

```
$Class = new Test();

if ($Class->Return_Test() === false){
  echo "Returned False";
}else{
  echo "Hasn't Returned false";
}
```

This will output returned false, because no param has been specified, so the function will treat the expected variable as false.

But:

```
if ($Class->Return_Test("Input") !== false){
  echo "Returned False"; 
}else{
  echo "Hasn't returned false"; 
}
```

Because A String is passed into the function, the expected variable is treated as a string, and not as the default. so the output will be:

> Hasn't returned false

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo "With no arguments: ";
get_news();

echo "With a slug (abc): ";
get_news('abc');

echo "No arguments No define: ";
get_news_no_false();

function get_news($slug = FALSE) {
    var_dump($slug);
}
function get_news_no_false($slug) {
    var_dump($slug);
}
?>
```

if you not define function get_news_no_false($slug) no set

> $slug = FALSE

you will get error

```
<?php
echo "With no arguments: ";
get_news();

echo "With a slug (abc): ";
get_news('abc');

echo "No arguments No define: ";
get_news_no_false();

function get_news($slug = FALSE) {
    var_dump($slug);
}
function get_news_no_false($slug = FALSE) {
    var_dump($slug);
}
?>
```

if you define $slug = FALSE it will return false automatic.